# `Symbol.iterator` in class and/or generator context - vaild ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6

While `Symbol.iterator` is to be found in the current [ES6 draft](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/555#issuecomment-90452650), can I clarify the validity of `Symbol.iterator` as a generator method of a class as follows (any references to the draft would be helpful):

```
class C {

    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: What part of the syntax are you unsure about, the `*`, the `[]`, the `(){…}`? The usage of the expression `Symbol.iterator`?

Comment: You mean the `class { … }` scope/body?

Comment: The name of the function, computed property names.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not normally one to look at the draft spec., however on this occasion:

ClassDeclaration https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-class-definitions

ClassElement

MethodDefinition https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-method-definitions

GeneratorMethod https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-generator-function-definitions

* PropertyName

PropertyName https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object-initializer

ComputedPropertyName

[ AssignmentExpression ]